# best practice for unlimited scroll list on html mobile app

Tags: android, ios, webkit, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm working on hybrid app for both ios and android. I'm dealing with crashing problem of unlimited list. The list will keep loading more data when you scroll, and it will crash if the list is too long. Any suggestion?

Comment: As the title says "html mobile app", I guess you're displaying your content in a WebView, and I don't think you can have an unlimited content in a WebView.

Comment: not exactly unlimited but I find a solution like a smart html slider using only 3 master pages and js to bind many data without loose the smoothness.